# Get the scrolltop of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scroll

I have this javascript:
In the javascript. You can click on the a element. I want the scrollTop in pixels of the a element. When i used console.log. See in my example. I get this:

```
[
Object
scrollTop: 649
__proto__: Object
]
```

But the problem is. How can i get the 649? I want to put the 649 in a variable.?

Javascript

```
$("a[href*='#']").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var offset = $(document).find($(e.target).attr('href')).offset();
        if(!offset)
            var offset = $(document).find($(e.target).parent().attr('href')).offset();

            var test = $({ scrollTop: offset.top });
            console.log(test);  

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `offset.top`.  You wrote code to wrap that in an object.  That code is not needed.

Comment: @MikeVierwind if this answer worked for you, please mark it as answer for both David's pleasure and people who have a simular question that end up here.

Comment: Yeah i know. But i must wait 10 minutes before i can accepted the answer

Comment: I'm going to be a stickler here, but this should be `offset().top` not `offset.top`.

Answer (score 2):

In jquery will be like this

```
$('#yourElement').offset().top;
```