# Execute a function after I load a div

Tags: javascript, youtube

I want to execute my function when I either scroll past or load `$("yt-next-continuation")`, this div is basically the extra videos that YouTube loads when you scroll to the bottom of the page.  What is the easiest way to do this?

What I basically want to do is, add overlay over the thumbnails when youtube loads in more videos when you scroll down their page. 
Atm my code is running when I first refresh their site, but not when more videos load in.

Comment: I would recommend providing more details about your existing code, e.g. js and html code samples, this will increase a chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: My code works fine, but Im looking to execute my current code when youtube loads in more videos when you scroll down their page. I edited in more details on my post anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at those two questions:

[Get the scrolltop of the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847276/get-the-scrolltop-of-the-element)

[How to detect scroll position of page using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441065/how-to-detect-scroll-position-of-page-using-jquery)

As described you can get the top position of the element by:

```
$('#yourElement').offset().top;
```

And your current locations with:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

So just do this:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if( scroll > $('#yourElement').offset().top ){
        $("body").addClass("youReachedTheElementsPosition");
    }else
        $("body").removeClass("youReachedTheElementsPosition");
    }
});
```

And use some CSS to do whatever you like doing:

```
.youReachedTheElementsPosition span{color:red;}
```

You can add animations by using [transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

```
.youReachedTheElementsPosition span{transform: color 0.3s ease;}
```

Comment: The problem with this, is that it triggers too often. It triggers everytime I scroll just a tad.

Comment: I see, the issue with this code is that it only gets triggered when i'm at the bottom of the page, but it wont trigger underways because of youtube's dynamic system

Answer (score 0):

can use [scroll magic](http://scrollmagic.io/) to esecute event on div is visualized on page.
also can use this function.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  isScrolledIntoView($("#yt-next-continuation"));
});

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);
  var $window = $(window);

  var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window[0].innerHeight;

  var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

the function return true if div is displayed and can execute anything function on return true.

Comment: Tried this, but I cant seem to get it working. Maybe it just doesnt work with my div?

Comment: This elementi $("yt-next-continuation") isn't exist. You have to use a id of elementi Like this $("#yt-next-continuation")

Comment: Still not working when i'm adding a element to it. Can I add you on discord or smth and show you?